# Bind XSD element to List of items

Tags: jaxb, xsd

Is there a way to directly bind a list of elements to the wrapper element.  Note, I am currently generating these classes from the XSD.

What I mean is this:

```
<wrapperElement>
  <listItem />
  ...
  <listItem />
</wrapperElement>
```

Currently, this would unmarshal to the following objects:

```
SomeJaxbObject
  +WrapperElement

WrapperElement
  +List<ListItem> listItem
```

Is there a way to directly bind that wrapper element as a list of objects as follows:

```
SomeJaxbObject
  +List<ListItem> listItems
```

I'm guessing this would require some custom bindings through an xjb file.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="wrapperElement")
@XmlElement(name="listItem")
public List<ListItem> getListItems() {
    return listItems;
}
```

Comment: Going to edit my post, these classes are generated off of an xsd, how would I add that annotation through the xsd, or should I generate the xsd off of the objects.  Great blog btw, been making me experiment a bit =)

Comment: Based on the schema generated from the hand written classes, seems like a nested complex type handles what I need it to do. Accepted.